# ASP.NET MVC4 - A library to draw a world map and to draw circles on the map given a latitude/longitude and radius

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, google-maps, gis

I am looking for a simple solution to be able to draw a world map in an ASP.NET MVC4 application.  The particular View that will render the map will be strongly typed to a collection (IEnumerable) of Contact records (Contact being my object).  Within the Contact class I'll have a Latitude/Longitude/Radius.  I want to be able to put the points on the map indicating the latitude and longitude, and draw a circle on the map using the radius.

Does anyone know of any SIMPLE solutions?  I looked into Google Maps (they have a rich API) - but the piece I was missing from their solution was to be able to draw a shape on the map itself given latitude/longitude coordinates and a radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed possible with Google Maps API.

Try the following

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243684),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
      mapOptions);

  var circleOptions = {
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243684),
      radius: 2000000
  };
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
}
```

This will create a single single on the map on the US west coast.